# Making a copy of a object pandas column as a category type giving warning

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I'm making a copy of a pandas object column into a separate ordered column but I'm getting a warning and haven't figured out for the life of me how to do it the correct way.

I can't post the entire data frame up but here is the syntax I'm using:

```
marriage_cat_type = CategoricalDtype(categories= ['M_22', 'M_23', 'M_24', 'M_25', 'M_26', 'M_27', 'M_28', 'M_29', 'M_30'
                                                  , 'M_31', 'M_32', 'M_33', 'M_34', 'M_35', 'M_36', 'M_37', 'M_38', 'M_39'
                                                  , 'M_40', 'M_41', 'M_42', 'M_43', 'M_44', 'M_45', 'M_46', 'M_47', 'M_48'
                                                  , 'M_49', 'M_50', 'M_51', 'M_52', 'M_53', 'M_54', 'M_55', 'M_56', 'M_57'
                                                  , 'M_58', 'M_59', 'M_60', 'M_61', 'M_62', 'M_63', 'M_64', 'M_65', 'M_66'
                                                  , 'M_67', 'M_68', 'M_69', 'M_70', 'M_71', 'M_72', 'M_73', 'M_74', 'M_75'
                                                  , 'M_76', 'M_77', 'M_78', 'M_79', 'M_80', 'M_81', 'M_82', 'M_999', 'S_18'
                                                  , 'S_19', 'S_20', 'S_21', 'S_22', 'S_23', 'S_24', 'S_25', 'S_26', 'S_27'
                                                  , 'S_28', 'S_29', 'S_30', 'S_31', 'S_32', 'S_33', 'S_34', 'S_35', 'S_36'
                                                  , 'S_37', 'S_38', 'S_39', 'S_40', 'S_41', 'S_42', 'S_43', 'S_44', 'S_45'
                                                  , 'S_46', 'S_47', 'S_48', 'S_49', 'S_50', 'S_51', 'S_52', 'S_53', 'S_54'
                                                  , 'S_55', 'S_56', 'S_57', 'S_58', 'S_59', 'S_60', 'S_61', 'S_62', 'S_63'
                                                  , 'S_64', 'S_65', 'S_66', 'S_67', 'S_68', 'S_69', 'S_70', 'S_71', 'S_72'
                                                  , 'S_73', 'S_74', 'S_75', 'S_77', 'S_79', 'S_999'], ordered = True)

coll_train['marriage_statusXage_codes'] = coll_train['marital_statusXage2'].astype(marriage_cat_type)
```

I'm getting this warning.

> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py:2:
>   SettingWithCopyWarning:  A value is trying to be set on a copy of a
>   slice from a DataFrame. Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] =
>   value instead
>
> See the caveats in the documentation:
>   http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy

And I've tried this resulting in failure:

> coll_train['marriage_statusXage_codes'] = coll_train.loc[:,
>   'marital_statusXage2'].astype(marriage_cat_type)

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a chained assignment issue.  That may be manipulated by `pd.set_option('chained_assignment',None|'warn'|'raise')`.

The warnings are turned on, and Pandas does not like `coll_train`.

There are a couple options:  Make sure `coll_train` is the source dataframe you intend to modify (which you are doing by placing a new column named `marriage_statusXage_codes` in it).  If it is, and Pandas is wrong, set `pd.set_option('chained_assignment',None)`. Can Pandas be wrong about that? I don't know.

Here is an illustration of setting a value on a slice.

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.compat import StringIO

print(pd.__version__)

csvdata = StringIO("""date,LASTA,LASTB,LASTC
1999-03-15,2.5597,8.20145,16.900
1999-03-31,2.7724,7.73057,16.955
1999-04-01,2.8321,7.63714,17.500
1999-04-06,2.8537,7.63703,17.750""")

df = pd.read_csv(csvdata, sep=",", index_col="date", parse_dates=True, infer_datetime_format=True)

pd.set_option('chained_assignment','warn')

a_slice = df['1999-03-31':'1999-04-01']
print(id(df), id(a_slice))
# generates the warning
a_slice['LASTA'] = 10
# original does not have the data set on a slice!
print(df[df['LASTA'] == 10]['LASTA'].any())

# create a new object to which values can be set, no warning.
a_slice = a_slice.copy()
a_slice['LASTA'] = 10
print(a_slice[a_slice['LASTA'] == 10]['LASTA'].any())
```

Results

```
0.20.3
(4549520208, 4594637776)
slicecopy.py:20: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
  a_slice['LASTA'] = 10
False
True
```